# Passing Bash shell varialbes in AWK. One regex works the other does not

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following bash script called bank_scpt.txt:

```
#!/bin/bash
  

anz="$1"
wp="$2"

# anz fixed cost search patterns:
anz_fc="^Aver"

# wp fixed cost search patterns:
wp_fc="2degrees"


# Preperation to get anz file ready for concatenation.
anz="$(awk -v r="$anz_fc" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 {split($7,a,"/"); print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1], $6, $2, $3, $4, "az" OFS ($6 > 0 ? "vi" : $2~r ? "fc" : "vc")}' "$anz" | column -s $'\t' -t)"

# Preperation to get wp file ready for concatenation.
wp="$(awk -v r="$wp_fc" 'BEGIN{FS="," ; OFS="\t"} NR>1 && $3~r {gsub(/"/, "", $0) ; split($1,a,"/"); print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1], $2, $3, $4, $5, "wp", "fc"}' "$wp" | column -s $'\t' -t)"

echo "$anz" "$wp" |head -n 4
echo "$anz" "$wp" |tail -n 4
```

The idea behind this script is to concatenate two bank account txt files: anz.txt and wp.txt

When I run:

```
./bank_scpt.txt anz.txt wp.txt
```

I get the following desired output (Please note az and wp in column six indicate the bank text files the records come from az = anz.txt and wp = wp.txt):

```
2021-03-31  -8.50     Monthly A/C Fee          az            vc
2021-03-31  -250.00   Rutherford & Bond        4835********  8848   C      az  vc
2021-03-31  -131.60   Avery Johnson            Avery Johnso  592315        az  fc
2021-03-31  50.00     Collins Tf               127 Driver    Crescent      az  vi
2020-12-29  -71.50  2degrees Mobile Ltd  DIRECT DEBIT  2365653  wp  fc
2021-01-27  -70.00  2degrees Mobile Ltd  DIRECT DEBIT  2365653  wp  fc
2021-02-26  -70.00  2degrees Mobile Ltd  DIRECT DEBIT  2365653  wp  fc
2021-03-26  -70.00  2degrees Mobile Ltd  DIRECT DEBIT  2365653  wp  fc
```

However when I use a regex such as wp_fc="^2degr" I get the following output (the wp.txt file is completely ignored):

```
2021-03-31  -8.50     Monthly A/C Fee          az            vc
2021-03-31  -250.00   Rutherford & Bond        4835********  8848   C      az  vc
2021-03-31  -131.60   Avery Johnson            Avery Johnso  592315        az  fc
2021-03-31  50.00     Collins Tf               127 Driver    Crescent      az  vi
2020-04-09  64.40     Body Corporate           Batchelor     1010 & 1036   az  vi
2020-04-09  17.25     A D & C H Bailey         Aron Bailey   az            vi
2020-04-06  46.00     Jm  Lymburn              13 Thornley   Titahi        az  vi
2020-04-02  17.25     A D & C H Bailey         Aron Bailey   az            vi
```

My question is why am I able to use anz_fc="^Aver" but not wp_fc="^2degr"? And how can I change the second awk command so I can indeed use wp_fc="^2degr"?

I include here and excerpt of the original files:

```
head -n 5 anz.txt

Type    Details Particulars Code    Reference   Amount  Date    ForeignCurrencyAmount   ConversionCharge
Bank Fee    Monthly A/C Fee             -8.50   31/03/2021      
Eft-Pos Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C    210331123119    -250.00 31/03/2021  
Payment Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  Labour  -131.60 31/03/2021      
Bill Payment    Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent    I1600   50.00   31/03/2021


head -n 5 wp.txt

Date,Amount,Other Party,Description,Reference,Particulars,Analysis Code
01/04/2020,478.26,"ACC","Salary",,"ACC WKLY CMP","TO 02Apr2020"
02/04/2020,-7.50,"Edorne Labog","AUTOMATIC PAYMENT",,"Christian","Netflix"
02/04/2020,-150.00,"Christian rent cover","AUTOMATIC PAYMENT",,"146 Coromand",
26/03/2021,-70.00,"2degrees Mobile Ltd","DIRECT DEBIT","2365653",,"10009701292"
```

Please note that wp.txt is a csv file that I saved as a txt file.

Comment: It looks to me that the failing command has the wrong field separator. So the regex that you pass via a variable is not finding a match as the fields are differently defined.

Comment: I vote to close this due to a typo.

Comment: wp.txt is comma seperated. I have change it to from FS="," to OFS="\t". What then is the typo?

Comment: You are expected to post `anz.txt` and `wp.txt` corresponding to the output.

Comment: Your regex won't work because your fields are wrapped around quotes. The real problem is you're using awk to parse a CSV that may also contain a comma in its field values. Consider using real solutions like [this](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: @ChristianHick aha, sorry. I do not see the original input file, so it is hard for us to explain what is happening then.

Comment: We can't tell you why your regexp doesn't match your input if you don't show us your input.

Comment: Sorry I have added the original files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some fields of `wp.txt` are enclosed with double quotes, I assume
the field which starts with `2degree` will be the same. (Although your
provided `wp.txt` unfortunately misses the crutial lines of `2degree`.)
Then the condition `$3~r` in your awk script is testing `"2degree"`
against the pattern `^2degree` which fails.
Then modify the line:

```
wp_fc="^2degr"
```

to something like:

```
wp_fc="^\"2degr"
```

then it will work.

As side notes:

- It is always recommended to post the consistent set of input file(s),
  your script, the result, and your expected result. Your provided
  input files are not related with your initially posted output at all
  and we cannot reproduce the problem.
- You better to avoid putting the `txt` suffix to the executable script file.
  It works, but is confusing.

Comment: A big thank you tshiono. This does work. You guys are amazing. I will take your comments on board.

Comment: I have a question though. I thought I had got rid of all quotation marks in wp.txt when I used ```gsub(/"/, "", $0)```.  And when I convert the file to \t separated the regex that is passed to wp.txt should behave in the same way as for anz.txt. I don't really understand why some fields in wp.txt are still enclosed with double quotes. Is this because I saved a csv file as a txt file?

Comment: I have replaced the last line of the input file wp.txt with the crucial 2degrees line.

Comment: You are indeed removing the double quotes with `gsub(/"/, "", $0)`, but
the gsub() function is applied **after** evaluating the condition
`NR>1 && $3~r` where the quotes still remain. Am I answering your question?

Comment: Yes thanks. That explains then why I had a typo rather than it being some other issue. I had been looking in the wrong places.